# ordinary differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to understand how the solution of this equation goes:
$$\frac{y^2-1}{y}\cdot \sin(x^3)=\frac{dy}{dx}$$ with initial condition $y(0)=-0.5$
I would like to understand if the solution can cross the line $y=0$.
Because as far as I see when the solution approaches this line, it gets infinitival incline, but then it can't be bounded by any  horizontal line.

someone could help?

Comment: isn't it separable variable?

Comment: a numerical solution by wolfram shows it crosses $y=0$.

Comment: Could you show me the numerical solution?

Comment: The thing is, with the initial condition you've listed, $y(x)$ goes to $0$ and then stays there for a while, before going back down (and up again, since the solution is periodic). However, this is only true of the **real part** of $y$. In fact, when [plotting both the real and the imaginary parts](http://www5b.wolframalpha.com/Calculate/MSP/MSP14841idb793ec96icbic00001b3bed88f81d00bi?MSPStoreType=image/gif&s=44&w=465.&h=204.&cdf=RangeControl), the solution is a sinusoidal (sort of) with $\mathsf{Re}(y)=0$ when $\mathsf{Im}(y)>0$ and $\mathsf{Im}(y)=0$ when $\mathsf{Re}(y)<0$.

Comment: Actually y(0) is real hence y(x) is real for every "time" x such that y(x) exists, and, for every nonzero y(0) such that |y(0)|<1, this is for every x in [0,x*) for some finite x* depending on y(0). At the end of the trajectory, that is, when x -> x*, one has y(x) -> 0 and |y'(x)| -> +oo.